# Iptables command analog in Windows

Tags: windows, networking, powershell, firewall, iptables

iptables -I FORWARD  -s 192.168.1.100 -p udp --dport 27000:27200 --match string --algo kmp --string 76561198923445525 -j ACCEPT

I need simply analog of that working command within windows OS, for example powershell or....cmd...whatever.

Basically we have an user with ID connecting to server.
With the command we ACCEPT specified string ID on ports 27000:27200 within 192.168.1.100 local server.
How to make this works without iptables?

Comment: have you taken a look at `Get-Command *firewall*` yet? [*grin*]

Comment: Actually we need specify like word or string or numeric ID which filter will accept for pass firewall, and other will be just dropped, i cant figure out which exactly function can be used for that.

Comment: try taking a look at the output of `Show-NetFirewallRule` for some ideas. if that doesn't work for you, then i suggest reading up on the firewall cmdlets in the MSDocs site ... and doing a bunch of net searching. ///// i never have used any of that stuff, so i am well beyond my skill level. good luck! [grin]

Answer (score 0):

This will be fairly close. The windows firewall allows for authenticated connections (user mapping), but this may not work for you, depending on what kind of client is connecting, and whether it supports this:

```
New-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName My-Firewall-Rule `
    -Direction Inbound `
    -Enabled True `
    -Action Allow `
    -Protocol UDP `
    -LocalPort 27000 `
    -LocalAddress 192.168.1.100 `
    -Authentication Required `
    -RemoteUser "D:(A;;CC;;;$UserSID)"
```

Replace `$UserSID` with the actual SID of the user to auth.

This is not exactly the same, and I don't believe windows really has the same functionality as the FORWARD chain in iptables without some of the routing features

```
# Basic maintenance commands:
Get-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName My-Firewall-Rule | format-list *  ## show all properties
Remove-NetFirewallRule -DisplayName My-Firewall-Rule  ## Delete your rule

# Enable detailed logging:
Set-NetFirewallProfile -LogAllowed True -LogFileName %SystemRoot%\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log

# Watch log:
Get-Content -Tail 10 -Wait "C:\windows\System32\LogFiles\Firewall\pfirewall.log"
```

For anything else, check the examples and documentation in `Get-Help New-NetFirewallRule -Full` or the [web docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/netsecurity/set-netfirewallprofile). Consider adding more information to your question about what you tried so far, and what client/server OS is in use.